# message.Attachments.ContentURL differences between Bot Emulator and production

Tags: botframework

In my bot (using C# version of BotBuilder) I expect to receive attached files from users.

I am accepting them by processing message.Attachments object.
When running in Emulator for attached file I will get ContentURL like this:

> http://localhost:9000/content/8a684db8?file=IMG-20160503-WA0002.jpg

from here I parse the URL to get to the filename and store it in local azure storage blob.

When I deploy my bot to azure and uploading files from Telegram (only chat app I connected so far) same file is posted with URL like this:

> https://bcattachmentsprod.blob.core.windows.net/635994216000000000/3DOUR10S0J2IL4

from here I am loosing filename, trying to inspect other message.Attachments properties it does not seem to be there. Making WebRequst on this URL in a hope to have filename somewhere in the header also does not render results

Is this an intended behavior for posting URL when deployed to Azure and if yes, how can I get to the filename that user has attached?
I seem to like how ContentURL is formed when running under Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with BotBuilder, but the blob name is always part of the URL that serves as the address for that blob.

The storage emulator uses well-known endpoints. For Blob storage, the URL will always have this address, where "mycontainer" is the name of your container and "myblob" is the name of your blob. So as you can see, the blob name is part of the URL path.

http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/mycontainer/myblob

The emulator uses this URL format because it is addressing a resource on your local computer.

In your Azure storage account in the cloud, the URL will look like this, where "myaccount" is the name of your storage account, "mycontainer" is the name of your container, and "myblob" is the name of your blob:

https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob

In your example above, "file=IMG-20160503-WA0002.jpg" is not part of a Blob storage URL. Perhaps this is appended by BotBuilder?

Please see these topics for more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/

Comment: Thanks Tamra, I was referring to emulator as Bot Emulator, not local storage emulator. apologies for not being clear .